# How to convert a Time4J Duration to a count of minutes?

Tags: java, duration, minute, time4j

How do I convert a Time4J `Duration<ClockUnit>` to a number of minutes? I’m fine with truncating any seconds, I just want the whole minutes. A couple of simple examples probably explain the best:

- For `Duration.of(1, ClockUnit.HOURS)` I want 60.
- For `Duration.of(34, ClockUnit.SECONDS)` I want 0.

There isn’t any `toMinutes` method (like there is in `java.time.Duration`). I played around with a `Normalizer`, the `getTotalLength` method and a stream operation and got a 6 lines solution to work, but surely there is a simpler way?

The solutions for hours and seconds could also be interesting, but I expect them to be more or less trivial modifications of the solution for minutes.

**Link:** [Documentation of `net.time4j.Duration`](http://www.time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Normalize to minutes and use getPartialAmount()

We do need the normalizer. We get it from `ClockUnit.only()`. Then `getPartialAmount()` takes care of the rest.

```
    List<Duration<ClockUnit>> durations = Arrays.asList(
            Duration.of(1, ClockUnit.HOURS),
            Duration.of(34, ClockUnit.SECONDS));
    
    for (Duration<ClockUnit> dur : durations) {
        long minutes = dur.with(ClockUnit.MINUTES.only())
                .getPartialAmount(ClockUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.format("%s = %d minutes%n", dur, minutes);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> PT1H = 60 minutes
> PT34S = 0 minutes
> ```

As explained in the tutorial (link at the bottom), Time4J is mainly designed around chronological elements (or fields) like years, months, and yes, minutes. So in code we first need to convert the duration to a duration of only minutes, after which we can take out the value of the minutes element — now the only element in the duration (in the case of 14 seconds, there isn’t even any minutes element, but `getPartialAmount()` sensibly returns 0 in this case).

We should obviously wrap the conversion into a method:

```
private static final long durationToNumber(Duration<ClockUnit> dur, ClockUnit unit) {
    return dur.with(unit.only()).getPartialAmount(unit);
}
```

As a bonus this method gives us the conversion to hours or seconds for free:

```
    for (Duration<ClockUnit> dur : durations) {
        long hours = durationToNumber(dur, ClockUnit.HOURS);
        long seconds = durationToNumber(dur, ClockUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.format("%s = %d hours or %d seconds%n", dur, hours, seconds);
    }
```

> ```
> PT1H = 1 hours or 3600 seconds
> PT34S = 0 hours or 34 seconds
> ```

### Link

[Time4J Tutorial: Element centric approach](http://time4j.net/tutorial/elementcentric.html)